# Converting the list of numbers in hexadecimal string in C preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic, variadic-macros

How to convert the list of the 16bit numbers to the hexadecimal string like `"\x0f\x56\x44\xe0"`.

How do these 16 bit values look? They are the result of the macro expansion too `#define make_word(arg1, arg2) arg1 << 16 + arg2`. So the full call should look like:

`some_function(MAKE_HEX_STR(make_word(1, 2), make_word(3, 4), make_word(5, 6));`

and should expands to the:

`some_function("\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06);`

Comment: why don't you just use `strtoul()` to convert the string to an integer?

Comment: Why cannot you just cast your `unsigned short` array to `unsigned char`, and use that? It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note: `"\x01" "\x02"  "\x03" "\x04" "\x05" "\x06"` is the same as  `"\x01\x02"  "\x03\x04" "\x05\x06"` and `"\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06"`.  So the problem is now only how to make `1` --> `"\x01"`, `255` --> `"\xFF"` in the pre-processor,

Comment: @AntonKochkov: The preprocessor won't evaluate `arg1 << 16 + arg2` so if you really want to do this in the preprocessor you'll need to use BOOSTPP. (And, by the way, `arg1<<16 + arg2` won't fit in 16 bits unless `arg1` is 0. Maybe you meant the shift to be 8 bits.) But you'd probably be better off using string concatenation instead of arithmetic, as @chux suggests.

Comment: @rici yes, you right, this was a typo, of course I mean shift by 8 bits, but probably it isn't needed in case of the string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what task is behind your question, but it's possible that the following will help (requires C99 or more recent):

```
#define MAKE_WORD(x,y) x,y
#define MAKE_STR(...) ((char[]){__VA_ARGS__, 0})
```

See it [live on ideone](http://ideone.com/iG2S82). If you don't really need it to be a string, you could leave out the 0 terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) and specify the base as 16.

or you can try like this:

```
int x = yourNumber;
char result[5]; 
if (x <= 0xFFFF)
{
    sprintf(&result[0], "%04x", x);
}
```

Comment: I need to perform all this operation at the preprocessor level.